# Is this a good question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> ##### Which branch combines solipsism and monism?
>
> Which branch of philosophy builds upon and whole-heartedly accepts
> that only *self* exists and the *universe* is the part/creation of
> *self* by eliminating the possibility of independent *selves* and *universe* through Occam razor. Analogous to:
>
> 1. [Simulation hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis)
>    without the cynical assumption of an independent *being* doing
>    simulation.
> 2. [Dream argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_argument) without the implicit assumption of current reality being *real* and
>    moving past the skepticism to acceptance.
>
> My question is not focused on validity of such position though I would
> love reading thoughts on this.
>
> Imagine a dream ;) in which my actions are constrained that I can not
> fly. I am running away from the people trying to catch me. I reach a
> cliff. Technically it is my dream and I could eliminate those people
> or fly off but what happens is I jump down and wake up sweating. I see
> clear parallel with my "waking" life and want to know the arguments
> against (or for) this (or similar) position by better known name.

---

Any suggestion for improvements? I am getting *Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person*.

Comment: I would deem *branch* too generic and broad a term. I'd rather got with something more specific like "which sources written after 2010" or the like. Also, I'm not sure what a non-monistic solipsism should look like. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I would call it monistic-solipsism (or solipsist-monism :D) I claim that only self can be known and "everything" is part/creation of self (so monistic in a way)

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Regarding branch, I think I am looking for some -ism. Not sure what to call that categorization.

Comment: I posted https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/89748/35433 meanwhile. The perceived "error" was just a guiding notification.